# How to fix unresolvable circular reference when using Sentry with Spring Boot 2.6.x instead of 2.5.x?

Tags: spring-boot, sentry

With `org.springframework.boot` version `2.5.9`, thinks work fine, but with `2.6.0` (`2.6.1`, `2.6.2`, `2.6.3`), I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sentryOptions': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

(full log: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/be7810282a06b538ccee0078ab2267aa)

Here is my minimal example to reproduce the issue:

`Application.kt`:

```kotlin
package com.acme.foo.bar

import io.sentry.spring.EnableSentry
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@EnableSentry
@Configuration
class SentryConfiguration

@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

`IntegrationTest.kt`:

```
package com.acme.foo.bar.integration

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class FullStackTest {
    @Test
    fun init_context() {
    }
}
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.10"
}

group = "com.acme"
version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(group = "org.springframework.boot", name = "spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation(group = "io.sentry", name = "sentry-spring", version = "5.5.3")

    testImplementation(group = "org.springframework.boot", name = "spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-test-junit")
}

tasks {
    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }

    withType<Test> {
        testLogging.exceptionFormat = org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or maybe `sentry-spring` just does work with Spring Boot `2.6.x` (yet)?

Comment: In `sentry-spring` we have a circular bean dependency that we've workedaround with @Lazy. Circular dependencies are not allowed by default in Spring Boot 2.6 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27652). Your approach to use `sentry-spring-boot-starter` instead is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Instead of `io.sentry:sentry-spring` one has to use `io.sentry:sentry-spring-boot-starter` in the dependencies and then remove the following from the code:

```kotlin
@EnableSentry
@Configuration
class SentryConfiguration
```

I've just tested in my actual project, and logged errors are still sent to Sentry correctly.